# Broadcasting shape in pymc3 deterministics

Tags: python, numpy, shapes, pymc3, broadcasting

I need help discerning how to apply shapes correctly in my pymc3 model.
The following is the classic jawbone study for showing repeated sampling. In the following model, my data has shape `(20,4)`. Take `ages` to be the x values with shape `(4,)`. `b0` and `b1` have shape `(1,)` and `z` is where I run into problems with shape.

This model is basically fitting 20 lines (for 20 different children) each with a unique intercept (that's what `z` is). The following model WORKS but is not how I would like to declare shapes:

```
with pm.Model() as model_1:
    b0 = pm.Normal('b0', mu=0, sd=10)
    b1 = pm.Normal('b1', mu=0, sd=10)
    sb = pm.HalfCauchy('sb', 10)
    sw = pm.HalfCauchy('sw', 10)

    z = pm.Normal('z', mu=0, sd=sb, shape=(len(data), 1))

    mu = b0 + b1 * ages + z
    sd = sw
    like = pm.Normal('y', mu=mu, sd=sd, observed=data)
```

It is unintuitive to me to have to add the extra `,1)` to the shape of z in order for it to broadcast correctly to my data. I would much rather define `z` like

```
z = pm.Normal('z', mu=0, sd=sb, shape=len(data)
mu = b0 + b1 * ages + z
```

but that is not able to be broadcasted correctly for `mu`. How can I correctly broadcast these shapes for the `mu` equation?

Comment: `shape=(data)` actually cast into `(len(data), )` internally in PyMC3, so I actually suggest you keep `shape=(len(data), 1)` and reshape `ages` into `(1, 4)` to make sure the broast is correct (explicit is better than implicit ;-) ).